# DNS Zone A record for domain

Tags: dns

Is there any contradiction of having A record for a zone name?
I know very experienced administrator who didn't want to add A record for zone names, and I don't know why. If the zone name is `example.com`, there will be no A record for `example.com`, only for hosts like `www`, etc.

So, is there a valid reason not to add A records for zone names?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about DNS as a concept, not about unix/linux implementation

Comment: I also do not particularly enjoy it being badly worded in english, underhanded and from someone playing power games. Some things are better left unsaid, namely discussing if someone "experienced" is doing it right or wrong.

Comment: This subject drew too much unhealthy emotions in my opinion and I really do not like to be accused of things I simply did not do or even intended to do. My question is only a result of need to pursue knowledge and I'm sad (and my friends at work are too) that we cannot ask him personally. And yes, my english isn't the best, I'm still learning; grammar is my weakest point I think. I basically agree with the @JennyD . Maybe deleting the question isn't the bad idea too.

Comment: @kmwil If the domain owners don't want the apex domain to be browsable, there's no reason to add it. If they do add it, they also need to keep webserver config uptodate, and there'll be an extra record to keep updated. So if they don't need the record, why spend the time to set it up and keeping it up to date? But there's no technical reason in terms of the domain being unusable or anything. (Note that you **must not** use a CNAME for the apex record, because that will break stuff, but an A record is fine.)

Answer (score 0):

It's more and more common to have an A record for the domain itself, particularly for domains that host a web server. In this scenario either the primary website would be hosted on the domain name, or it would be hosted on the www with a redirect record configured for the domain name to send users to the full www website.

(Why not run the full website on the domain and on www? It's to do with de-duplication and SEO rankings.)

NB There may be good reason why this configuration is not wanted/required in some situations.

Comment: Could you say something about those situations, links are great too. I couldn't dig up anything good.

Comment: About good reasons could be needing glue records, or also as historically A records being used to point to emails servers.